# c realloc struct - g_hash_table

Tags: c, glib, realloc

I'm doing something similar to the following code. I have already gone through `AddtoStructFunction()` filling `mystruct` once. Now, what I would like to do is to append every new entry directly to the `mystruct` without having to free `mystruct` and iterate over again the whole `g_hash_table` containing the new key(s) to insert them into `mystruct`.

What would be a good way of doing this? realloc each new entry?

```
void InsertFunction(GHashTable *hash, char *str) {
    g_hash_table_insert(hash, str, "Richmond");
}

void AddtoStructFunction(struct dastruct **mystruct) {
    // initial fill with all elements of g_hash_table_size(g_hash_table) at the time AddtoStructFunction is called.
    mystruct = (struct dastruct **)malloc(sizeof(struct dastruct *)*g_hash_table_size(g_hash_table));
    g_hash_table_iter_init(&iter, g_hash_table);
    while (g_hash_table_iter_next(&iter, &key_, (gpointer) &val)) {
        mystruct[i] = (struct dastruct *)malloc(sizeof (struct dastruct));
        mystruct[i]->myKey = (gchar *) key_;
        i++;
    }
}

void AddExtraOnes(struct dastruct **mystruct, char *string) {
    // realloc mystruct here?
    // each time I call AddExtraOnes, I'd like to append them to mystruct
    mystruct[?]->myKey = string;
}

int i;
for(i = 0; i < 100000, i++){
    InsertFunction(g_hash_table, "RandomStrings");
}
AddtoStructFunction(mystruct);
...
// do this n times
AddExtraOnes(mystruct, "Boston");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `realloc` function to reallocate your array of struct pointers.  It will copy the existing data to the new array if it succeeds (if you have an array of 20 pointers to `mystruct` instances and `realloc` the array to contain 30, the first 20 will be the same as your original array).

Since you're using GLib, you might also consider `GArray` rather than a plain `mystruct**`.  It handles re-allocation for you.